# Using self signed certificate for Windows phone HTTPS(HTTP over SSL) communication

Tags: http, windows-phone-8, ssl, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a Windows Phone 8/8.1 application.I need to do HTTP communication over SSL ie. HTTPS communication.server will send a certificate in web service response. As far I know Windows phone supports all built-in CA's certificates and just by adding `https://` protocol scheme we can have secure communication, everything is managed by Windows Phone.

My question is: **Can we do `HTTPS` communication using self signed certificate installed on device and present on server?**. Will I be able to do this?
Yes, no and why?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the certificate ti the device (for example publishing the .cre file somewhere and then opening the file in IE and installing) and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for answer...but I installed self signed certificate on windows phone device,also added it on server.When I fire "https" request it gives response with StatusCode "NotFound".

Comment: "added it on server"? Just install the existing https certificate from the server on the device

Comment: I Installed it.Link opens in browser saying that "We're having trouble with this site's security certificate".I think its because certificate is not from trusted CA.I can obviously continue on surfing in browser.but in my WP8 app I get NotFound response, using HttpClient library.